# usage of ' indeed to me ' vs to me indeed

Tags: grammaticality

The gift is very useful  indeed to me .
The gift is very useful to me  indeed.
Where I place  ' indeed ' ?
Can I use ' indeed ' in this sentence ?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if used to strengthen a "very", the "indeed" goes to the end of the sentence:

> The gift is very useful to me indeed.

An alternative would be to place it after "is", though with the "very" this may seem to some like you're overemphasising:

> The gift is indeed very useful to me.

Or in speech, if replying to show agreement with something, it could even go at the start of the sentence.

> Did you enjoy the gift?
>
> Indeed, it's very useful to me.

Source (for the first two examples, at least): http://www.englishpractice.com/common-mistakes/sentence/

Comment: I think putting ***indeed*** at the *start* of a statement often implies "refutation" of some prior statement or implication, or something along the lines of *I would go so far as to say...*. *"I suppose you don't like my gift", "No. it's fine! Indeed, it's very useful to me!*